# Why the LCP (largest contentful paint) value would get worse over time without changes in the site?

Tags: seo

I'm not using wordpress, but a LAMP website of my own creation.

For some reason, and without me doing anything on the website, the Largest Contentful Paint values have gotten worse and worse every month from the past year.

I've noticed that the website received more and more visitors as well, could that be related? How? Why?[image]

Comment: Is your site on a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Hi there! No, it's on a VPN

Comment: It seems like field data are used. Your population might have changed for instance towards low bandwidth or cpu devices?

Comment: I doubt it, it's very wide (aka, economic backgrounds, gender, age, location within the country Argentina-).

Answer (score 1):

It **is** because you are getting more traffic and with that, Google is getting better/more data about your LCP - the new lower LCP is the real one, the previous numbers were based on little traffic... so it didn't really got worse, it's just that now you know the real number.